# jQuery move value to last position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the object as,

```
var names =["LET_ABC","PET_DEF","Num_123","Num_456","SET_GHI","RET_JKL"];
```

Now i have to move the value which contains "`Num`" to the last which means after the "`Num`" value there should be no values.

This is how i add the value to the array,

```
 result.each(function () {
        var tempObject = {},
            attributes = $(this).data();
        names.push(attributes.prefix+ '_' + attributes.value)
    });
```

Can i somehow manipulate the above code to make the "`Num`" values move at last.

I need something like,

```
var names =["LET_ABC","PET_DEF","SET_GHI","RET_JKL","Num_123","Num_456"];
```

Comment: Could you please include all relevant code (Jquery,Html,Css).

Comment: What are the possible prefix values?

Comment: You can loop through the elements, splice those 2 into another array and then append the new array at the end of the old one (merging them). Or are you  just asking if jQuery can do this more easily? Edit: wow jmtalarn wrote this as an answer at the same time as I wrote this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Working example (with explanation in comments):-***

```js
var names =["LET_ABC","LET_DEF","Num_123","Num_456","LET_GHI","LET_JKL"];//your array

function movetoLast(names,checkword){// function with array and checking prefix

 $(names).each(function(index,value){ // iterate over array
   if(value.indexOf(checkword) >= 0){ // check value have that prefix or not in it
      names.push(names.splice(names.indexOf(value), 1)[0]); // if yes move that value to last in array
   }
 });
 
 return names; // return modified array
}


var names = movetoLast(names,"Num");// call function

console.log(names); // print modified array in console
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Worked perfect.Thanks. Let me know if there is a possible way to modify it while append into array.

Comment: @iamCR  glad to help you.:):). I din't get you here:- `Let me know if there is a possible way to modify it while append into array`

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
  if(names[i].match("^Num")){   
    names.push(names.splice(i, 1)[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The prefix could be different. Let me update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.simple use [`Array#filter`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihrO297eLTAhVKvo8KHUFPBRYQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHgB7IyOa22NG7kCsGZ1ldwMUmkiA) and [`Array#concat`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjg_6zM7eLTAhUKr48KHcJYA1YQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fconcat&usg=AFQjCNEPKjgucUe0cbw8oXqOzUzvOGw1oA)

```js
var names = ["LET_ABC", "PET_DEF", "Num_123", "Num_456", "SET_GHI", "RET_JKL"];
console.log(names.filter(a => !a.match(/(\d+)/g)).concat(names.filter(a => a.match(/(\d+)/g))))
```

Comment: OP says that prefix could be different

Answer (score 0):

I would put the numbers in a separate array to concatenate the two arrays at the end.

```
result.each(function () {
            var tempObject = {}, attributes = $(this).data();
            var numsArray = [];        
            if (attributes.prefix==Num){
              numsArray.push(attributes.prefix+ '_' + attributes.value);
            }else{
              names.push(attributes.prefix+ '_' + attributes.value)
            }

            names.concat(numsArray); 
     });
```

Comment: If you make a snippet, please make a working snippet

Answer (score 0):

Use **push** to add a value to the end of an array if it has the "Num" prefix and use **unshift** to add a value to the beginning of an array if it does not have the "Num" prefix. Working code:

```
var names =["LET_ABC","PET_DEF","Num_123","Num_456","SET_GHI","RET_JKL"];

$(document).ready(function(){
    result_array = [];
    $.each(names, function(index, value){
        if (value.substring(0,3)=="Num"){
            result_array.push(value);
        } else{
            result_array.unshift(value);
        };
    });
    console.log(result_array);
});
```